# Connecting to some Bluetooth LE devices crashes the Qt app on OSX

Tags: macos, qt, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a Qt app on OSX which scans and connects to Bluetooth low energy devices. Due to lacking the necessary APIs in Qt to access manufacturer specific data in the advertisement, I have to connect to each device discovered during a scan in order to check if it is the type of device I am looking for. My problem now is that, when connecting to some of the devices, I can successfully get information about manufacturer and serial number; but when connecting to some other devices, the app just crashes.

The crashing happens when calling the `QLowEnergyController`'s method `connectToDevice()`. Below is the trace:

```
2015-10-21 11:33:19.875 MyApp[24076:1272507] -[OS_dispatch_mach performNextRequest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe6cb7bbc40
2015-10-21 11:33:19.941 MyApp[24076:1272507] An uncaught exception was raised
2015-10-21 11:33:19.941 MyApp[24076:1272507] -[OS_dispatch_mach performNextRequest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe6cb7bbc40
2015-10-21 11:33:19.941 MyApp[24076:1272507] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8afc3bd2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff986c2dd4 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b02d0ed -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8af343d1 ___forwarding___ + 1009
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8af33f58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   QtBluetooth                         0x0000000104d23588 -[OSXBTCentralManager peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:] + 760
    6   CoreBluetooth                       0x00007fff9356d9ee -[CBCentralManager xpcConnection:didReceiveMsg:args:] + 149
    7   CoreBluetooth                       0x00007fff935777de __34-[CBXpcConnection handleMsg:args:]_block_invoke + 77
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff887498ff _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8873e453 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff88751c1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1685
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8af79789 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8af3873d __CFRunLoopRun + 1949
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8af37d38 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff947e9d55 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
    15  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff947e9b8f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
    16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff947e99cf _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b72df3a _DPSNextEvent + 1067
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b72d369 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b721ecc -[NSApplication run] + 682
    20  libqcocoa.dylib                     0x000000010508408d _ZN21QCocoaEventDispatcher13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 2189
    21  QtCore                              0x00000001042c107d _ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 381
    22  QtCore                              0x00000001042c3f5a _ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv + 346
    23  MyApp                              0x00000001034bdf3f main + 2319
    24  MyApp                              0x00000001034bd1e4 start + 52
)
2015-10-21 11:33:19.967 MyApp[24076:1272507] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[OS_dispatch_mach performNextRequest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe6cb7bbc40'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8afc3bd2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff986c2dd4 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b02d0ed -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8af343d1 ___forwarding___ + 1009
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8af33f58 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   QtBluetooth                         0x0000000104d23588 -[OSXBTCentralManager peripheral:didUpdateValueForCharacteristic:error:] + 760
    6   CoreBluetooth                       0x00007fff9356d9ee -[CBCentralManager xpcConnection:didReceiveMsg:args:] + 149
    7   CoreBluetooth                       0x00007fff935777de __34-[CBXpcConnection handleMsg:args:]_block_invoke + 77
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff887498ff _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff8873e453 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff88751c1c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1685
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8af79789 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8af3873d __CFRunLoopRun + 1949
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8af37d38 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
    14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff947e9d55 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
    15  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff947e9b8f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
    16  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff947e99cf _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
    17  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b72df3a _DPSNextEvent + 1067
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b72d369 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
    19  AppKit                              0x00007fff8b721ecc -[NSApplication run] + 682
    20  libqcocoa.dylib                     0x000000010508408d _ZN21QCocoaEventDispatcher13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 2189
    21  QtCore                              0x00000001042c107d _ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 381
    22  QtCore                              0x00000001042c3f5a _ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv + 346
    23  MyApp                              0x00000001034bdf3f main + 2319
    24  MyApp                              0x00000001034bd1e4 start + 52
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

I have a few questions to ask:

1. What kind of BT devices or settings refuse/filter incoming connections? When using [LightBlue](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-explorer-bluetooth/id557428110?mt=8) to connect to those BLE devices, it says "The peripheral disconnected while being interrogated" but LightBlue doesn't just crash.
2. Can we set Qt's Bluetooth DiscoveryAgent to only scan for low energy device? Did not see it in documents but still want to ask.
3. Since the crash seems to be happening inside the Qt library, how can I catch that exception and ignore that device? I did the following which doesn't work.

   ```
   try { m_controller->connectToDevice(); }
   catch(...) {  //Log("UNKNOWN EXCEPTION");  }
   ```

I would appreciate if someone can provide information regarding this issue or the above questions. The issue may be specific, but answers to the questions can help me or someone else. Thanks.

Comment: Found the answer to my question 2: there is a bug/todo in Qt's Jira system:     QTBUG-46253    QBluetoothDeviceDiscoveryAgent always performs classic and btle scan.

Comment: Coming back to answer my first question: BLE Broadcaster is a type of device that does not accept incoming connections, but rather pushes out the data is has inside its device discovery, or advertisement, data.